# Contour plot from data.txt using matplotlib

Tags: python, plot, contour

I am a new one for python.
I am trying to plot a contour plot.
I have data set in data.txt

```
enter code here
#coding:utf-8

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []
z = []
f = open("data1.txt")
line = f.readline()
while line:
    c,d,e = line.split()
    x.append(c)
    y.append(d)
    z.append(e)

    line = f.readline()

f.close()

x = [ float ( x ) for x in x if x ]
y = [ float( y ) for y in y if y ]
z = [ float( z ) for z in z if z ]

fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')

ax.plot(x,y,z)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

and then I can get the figure like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Exe.png)

I hope it looks like this

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just want to provide more detail, but I can not find the edit.
data.txt like this:

```
0.166666657 0   0
0   0   0
0.166666657 0.100000001 0
0   0.100000001 0
0.333333313 0   0
0.333333313 0.100000001 0
0.49999997  0   0
0.49999997  0.100000001 0
0.833333254 0   0
0.833333254 0.100000001 0
1.166666627 0   0
1.166666627 0.100000001 0
1.499999881 0   0
1.499999881 0.100000001 0
1.874999881 0   0
1.874999881 0.100000001 0
2.249999762 0   0
2.249999762 0.100000001 0
2.624999762 0   0
2.624999762 0.100000001 0
2.999999762 0   0
2.999999762 0.100000001 0
3.399999857 0   0
3.399999857 0.100000001 0
3.799999952 0   0
3.799999952 0.100000001 0
4.199999809 0   0
4.199999809 0.100000001 0
4.599999905 0   0
4.599999905 0.100000001 0
5   0   0
5   0.100000001 0
0.166666657 1.100000024 0
0   1.100000024 0
0.333333313 1.100000024 0
0.49999997  1.100000024 0
0.833333254 1.100000024 0
1.166666627 1.100000024 0
1.499999881 1.100000024 0
1.874999881 1.100000024 0
2.249999762 1.100000024 0
2.624999762 1.100000024 0
2.999999762 1.100000024 0
3.399999857 1.100000024 0
3.799999952 1.100000024 0
4.199999809 1.100000024 0
4.599999905 1.100000024 0
5   1.100000024 0
0.166666657 2.139130354 0
0   2.139130354 0
0.333333313 2.139130354 0
0.49999997  2.139130354 0
0.833333254 2.139130354 0
1.166666627 2.139130354 0
1.499999881 2.139130354 0
1.874999881 2.139130354 0
2.249999762 2.139130354 0
2.624999762 2.139130354 0
2.999999762 2.139130354 0
3.399999857 2.139130354 0
3.799999952 2.139130354 0
4.199999809 2.139130354 0
4.599999905 2.139130354 0
5   2.139130354 0
0.166666657 3.178260803 0
0   3.178260803 0
0.333333313 3.178260803 0
0.49999997  3.178260803 0
0.833333254 3.178260803 0
1.166666627 3.178260803 0
1.499999881 3.178260803 0
1.874999881 3.178260803 0
2.249999762 3.178260803 0
2.624999762 3.178260803 0
2.999999762 3.178260803 0
3.399999857 3.178260803 0
3.799999952 3.178260803 0
4.199999809 3.178260803 0
4.599999905 3.178260803 0
5   3.178260803 0
0.166666657 4.217391491 0
0   4.217391491 0
0.333333313 4.217391491 0
0.49999997  4.217391491 0
0.833333254 4.217391491 0
1.166666627 4.217391491 0
1.499999881 4.217391491 0
1.874999881 4.217391491 0
2.249999762 4.217391491 0
2.624999762 4.217391491 0
2.999999762 4.217391491 0
3.399999857 4.217391491 0
3.799999952 4.217391491 0
4.199999809 4.217391491 0
4.599999905 4.217391491 0
5   4.217391491 0
0.166666657 5.256521702 0
0   5.256521702 0
0.333333313 5.256521702 0
0.49999997  5.256521702 2.83E-06
0.833333254 5.256521702 2.83E-06
1.166666627 5.256521702 0
1.499999881 5.256521702 0
1.874999881 5.256521702 0
2.249999762 5.256521702 0
2.624999762 5.256521702 0
2.999999762 5.256521702 0
3.399999857 5.256521702 0
3.799999952 5.256521702 0
4.199999809 5.256521702 0
4.599999905 5.256521702 0
5   5.256521702 0
0.166666657 6.29565239  8.05E-04
0   6.29565239  7.13E-04
0.333333313 6.29565239  0.001456573
0.49999997  6.29565239  0.002108717
0.833333254 6.29565239  0.001104275
1.166666627 6.29565239  4.31E-06
1.499999881 6.29565239  4.41E-07
1.874999881 6.29565239  1.51E-07
2.249999762 6.29565239  8.77E-08
2.624999762 6.29565239  3.19E-08
2.999999762 6.29565239  4.64E-09
3.399999857 6.29565239  0
3.799999952 6.29565239  0
4.199999809 6.29565239  0
4.599999905 6.29565239  0
5   6.29565239  0
0.166666657 7.3347826   0.001146442
0   7.3347826   7.14E-04
0.333333313 7.3347826   0.002594632
0.49999997  7.3347826   0.005290068
0.833333254 7.3347826   0.003493796
1.166666627 7.3347826   1.02E-05
1.499999881 7.3347826   1.57E-06
1.874999881 7.3347826   3.58E-07
2.249999762 7.3347826   3.00E-07
2.624999762 7.3347826   2.37E-07
2.999999762 7.3347826   1.27E-07
3.399999857 7.3347826   3.90E-08
3.799999952 7.3347826   9.40E-09
4.199999809 7.3347826   2.12E-09
4.599999905 7.3347826   1.88E-10
5   7.3347826   0
0.166666657 8.373912811 0.001143811
0   8.373912811 6.32E-04
0.333333313 8.373912811 0.002098797
0.49999997  8.373912811 0.005743471
0.833333254 8.373912811 0.004605132
1.166666627 8.373912811 1.37E-04
1.499999881 8.373912811 4.47E-06
1.874999881 8.373912811 2.96E-07
2.249999762 8.373912811 2.47E-07
2.624999762 8.373912811 2.42E-07
2.999999762 8.373912811 1.68E-07
3.399999857 8.373912811 8.93E-08
3.799999952 8.373912811 5.37E-08
4.199999809 8.373912811 3.07E-08
4.599999905 8.373912811 1.25E-08
5   8.373912811 5.02E-09
0.166666657 9.413043022 0.00184233
0   9.413043022 0.001671778
0.333333313 9.413043022 0.001969866
0.49999997  9.413043022 0.005147494
0.833333254 9.413043022 0.004489599
1.166666627 9.413043022 3.14E-04
1.499999881 9.413043022 8.36E-06
1.874999881 9.413043022 3.07E-07
2.249999762 9.413043022 6.62E-08
2.624999762 9.413043022 6.94E-08
2.999999762 9.413043022 8.02E-08
3.399999857 9.413043022 8.42E-08
3.799999952 9.413043022 7.29E-08
4.199999809 9.413043022 5.00E-08
4.599999905 9.413043022 2.44E-08
5   9.413043022 1.11E-08
0.166666657 10.45217419 0.002082661
0   10.45217419 0.002093853
0.333333313 10.45217419 0.002018111
0.49999997  10.45217419 0.005188842
0.833333254 10.45217419 0.004552273
1.166666627 10.45217419 3.55E-04
1.499999881 10.45217419 9.66E-06
1.874999881 10.45217419 4.04E-07
2.249999762 10.45217419 5.71E-08
2.624999762 10.45217419 7.03E-08
2.999999762 10.45217419 6.99E-08
3.399999857 10.45217419 6.44E-08
3.799999952 10.45217419 5.49E-08
4.199999809 10.45217419 4.20E-08
4.599999905 10.45217419 2.36E-08
5   10.45217419 1.19E-08
0.166666657 11.4913044  0.002068915
0   11.4913044  0.002088516
0.333333313 11.4913044  0.002010661
0.49999997  11.4913044  0.00519882
0.833333254 11.4913044  0.004531486
1.166666627 11.4913044  3.27E-04
1.499999881 11.4913044  8.68E-06
1.874999881 11.4913044  3.48E-07
2.249999762 11.4913044  6.64E-08
2.624999762 11.4913044  8.28E-08
2.999999762 11.4913044  7.60E-08
3.399999857 11.4913044  6.23E-08
3.799999952 11.4913044  5.33E-08
4.199999809 11.4913044  4.11E-08
4.599999905 11.4913044  2.32E-08
5   11.4913044  1.20E-08
0.166666657 12.53043461 0.002039805
0   12.53043461 0.00205601
0.333333313 12.53043461 0.001996976
0.49999997  12.53043461 0.00518821
0.833333254 12.53043461 0.004489759
1.166666627 12.53043461 2.94E-04
1.499999881 12.53043461 7.44E-06
1.874999881 12.53043461 2.93E-07
2.249999762 12.53043461 8.34E-08
2.624999762 12.53043461 9.43E-08
2.999999762 12.53043461 8.56E-08
3.399999857 12.53043461 6.54E-08
3.799999952 12.53043461 5.54E-08
4.199999809 12.53043461 4.20E-08
4.599999905 12.53043461 2.37E-08
5   12.53043461 1.28E-08
0.166666657 13.56956482 0.002015376
0   13.56956482 0.002027846
0.333333313 13.56956482 0.001984971
0.49999997  13.56956482 0.00516937
0.833333254 13.56956482 0.004446038
1.166666627 13.56956482 2.66E-04
1.499999881 13.56956482 6.17E-06
1.874999881 13.56956482 2.33E-07
2.249999762 13.56956482 8.64E-08
2.624999762 13.56956482 9.96E-08
2.999999762 13.56956482 9.09E-08
3.399999857 13.56956482 6.92E-08
3.799999952 13.56956482 5.97E-08
4.199999809 13.56956482 4.49E-08
4.599999905 13.56956482 2.50E-08
5   13.56956482 1.37E-08
0.166666657 14.60869598 0.001994169
0   14.60869598 0.002003726
0.333333313 14.60869598 0.001972914
0.49999997  14.60869598 0.00514606
0.833333254 14.60869598 0.004404811
1.166666627 14.60869598 2.44E-04
1.499999881 14.60869598 5.02E-06
1.874999881 14.60869598 1.86E-07
2.249999762 14.60869598 8.74E-08
2.624999762 14.60869598 1.00E-07
2.999999762 14.60869598 9.21E-08
3.399999857 14.60869598 7.31E-08
3.799999952 14.60869598 6.60E-08
4.199999809 14.60869598 4.99E-08
4.599999905 14.60869598 2.69E-08
5   14.60869598 1.43E-08
0.166666657 15.64782619 0.001974078
0   15.64782619 0.00198149
0.333333313 15.64782619 0.001958905
0.49999997  15.64782619 0.005118577
0.833333254 15.64782619 0.00436624
1.166666627 15.64782619 2.27E-04
1.499999881 15.64782619 4.16E-06
1.874999881 15.64782619 1.65E-07
2.249999762 15.64782619 8.83E-08
2.624999762 15.64782619 9.88E-08
2.999999762 15.64782619 7.91E-08
3.399999857 15.64782619 6.45E-08
3.799999952 15.64782619 7.41E-08
4.199999809 15.64782619 5.63E-08
4.599999905 15.64782619 2.85E-08
5   15.64782619 1.43E-08
0.166666657 16.68695641 0.0019543
0   16.68695641 0.001960144
0.333333313 16.68695641 0.001943025
0.49999997  16.68695641 0.00508678
0.833333254 16.68695641 0.004329463
1.166666627 16.68695641 2.15E-04
1.499999881 16.68695641 3.58E-06
1.874999881 16.68695641 1.47E-07
2.249999762 16.68695641 9.03E-08
2.624999762 16.68695641 9.72E-08
2.999999762 16.68695641 7.90E-08
3.399999857 16.68695641 6.91E-08
3.799999952 16.68695641 6.71E-08
4.199999809 16.68695641 4.71E-08
4.599999905 16.68695641 2.93E-08
5   16.68695641 1.37E-08
0.166666657 17.72608757 0.001934777
0   17.72608757 0.001939479
0.333333313 17.72608757 0.001926098
0.49999997  17.72608757 0.005051369
0.833333254 17.72608757 0.004294238
1.166666627 17.72608757 2.07E-04
1.499999881 17.72608757 3.31E-06
1.874999881 17.72608757 1.44E-07
2.249999762 17.72608757 9.24E-08
2.624999762 17.72608757 9.57E-08
2.999999762 17.72608757 9.21E-08
3.399999857 17.72608757 8.63E-08
3.799999952 17.72608757 7.10E-08
4.199999809 17.72608757 4.89E-08
4.599999905 17.72608757 2.94E-08
5   17.72608757 1.30E-08
0.166666657 18.76521683 0.001915514
0   18.76521683 0.001919387
0.333333313 18.76521683 0.001908651
0.49999997  18.76521683 0.00501325
0.833333254 18.76521683 0.004260369
1.166666627 18.76521683 2.03E-04
1.499999881 18.76521683 3.28E-06
1.874999881 18.76521683 1.62E-07
2.249999762 18.76521683 9.38E-08
2.624999762 18.76521683 9.44E-08
2.999999762 18.76521683 9.26E-08
3.399999857 18.76521683 8.98E-08
3.799999952 18.76521683 8.77E-08
4.199999809 18.76521683 6.38E-08
4.599999905 18.76521683 2.92E-08
5   18.76521683 1.23E-08
0.166666657 19.80434799 0.001896351
0   19.80434799 0.001899629
0.333333313 19.80434799 0.001890444
0.49999997  19.80434799 0.004972469
0.833333254 19.80434799 0.004226807
1.166666627 19.80434799 2.01E-04
1.499999881 19.80434799 3.37E-06
1.874999881 19.80434799 1.74E-07
2.249999762 19.80434799 9.48E-08
2.624999762 19.80434799 9.37E-08
2.999999762 19.80434799 7.90E-08
3.399999857 19.80434799 7.88E-08
3.799999952 19.80434799 9.01E-08
4.199999809 19.80434799 6.46E-08
4.599999905 19.80434799 2.90E-08
5   19.80434799 1.18E-08
0.166666657 20.84347916 0.001877118
0   20.84347916 0.001879973
0.333333313 20.84347916 0.001871425
0.49999997  20.84347916 0.004928756
0.833333254 20.84347916 0.004192216
1.166666627 20.84347916 2.01E-04
1.499999881 20.84347916 3.53E-06
1.874999881 20.84347916 1.90E-07
2.249999762 20.84347916 9.63E-08
2.624999762 20.84347916 9.34E-08
2.999999762 20.84347916 7.97E-08
3.399999857 20.84347916 8.21E-08
3.799999952 20.84347916 9.26E-08
4.199999809 20.84347916 6.55E-08
4.599999905 20.84347916 2.90E-08
5   20.84347916 1.15E-08
0.166666657 21.88260841 0.001857258
0   21.88260841 0.001860346
0.333333313 21.88260841 0.001851503
0.49999997  21.88260841 0.004882752
0.833333254 21.88260841 0.004156424
1.166666627 21.88260841 2.02E-04
1.499999881 21.88260841 3.73E-06
1.874999881 21.88260841 2.10E-07
2.249999762 21.88260841 9.82E-08
2.624999762 21.88260841 9.35E-08
2.999999762 21.88260841 9.51E-08
3.399999857 21.88260841 9.99E-08
3.799999952 21.88260841 9.55E-08
4.199999809 21.88260841 6.67E-08
4.599999905 21.88260841 2.93E-08
5   21.88260841 1.16E-08
0.166666657 22.92173958 0.001835249
0   22.92173958 0.001838622
0.333333313 22.92173958 0.00183039
0.49999997  22.92173958 0.004835702
0.833333254 22.92173958 0.004120183
1.166666627 22.92173958 2.03E-04
1.499999881 22.92173958 3.96E-06
1.874999881 22.92173958 2.35E-07
2.249999762 22.92173958 1.00E-07
2.624999762 22.92173958 9.41E-08
2.999999762 22.92173958 9.63E-08
3.399999857 22.92173958 1.03E-07
3.799999952 22.92173958 9.82E-08
4.199999809 22.92173958 6.83E-08
4.599999905 22.92173958 2.96E-08
5   22.92173958 1.14E-08
0.166666657 23.96086884 0.001811466
0   23.96086884 0.001814246
0.333333313 23.96086884 0.001808798
0.49999997  23.96086884 0.004788195
0.833333254 23.96086884 0.004083806
1.166666627 23.96086884 2.04E-04
1.499999881 23.96086884 4.22E-06
1.874999881 23.96086884 2.65E-07
2.249999762 23.96086884 1.02E-07
2.624999762 23.96086884 9.50E-08
2.999999762 23.96086884 9.73E-08
3.399999857 23.96086884 8.69E-08
3.799999952 23.96086884 8.26E-08
4.199999809 23.96086884 6.98E-08
4.599999905 23.96086884 2.88E-08
5   23.96086884 8.91E-09
0.166666657 25  0.001788157
0   25  0.001790103
0.333333313 25  0.001787562
0.49999997  25  0.004740176
0.833333254 25  0.004047134
1.166666627 25  2.06E-04
1.499999881 25  4.49E-06
1.874999881 25  2.97E-07
2.249999762 25  1.04E-07
2.624999762 25  9.61E-08
2.999999762 25  9.85E-08
3.399999857 25  8.92E-08
3.799999952 25  8.51E-08
4.199999809 25  7.10E-08
4.599999905 25  2.70E-08
5   25  5.35E-09
0.166666657 26.03913116 0.001766148
0   26.03913116 0.00176749
0.333333313 26.03913116 0.00176692
0.49999997  26.03913116 0.004691813
0.833333254 26.03913116 0.004010193
1.166666627 26.03913116 2.07E-04
1.499999881 26.03913116 4.78E-06
1.874999881 26.03913116 3.32E-07
2.249999762 26.03913116 1.05E-07
2.624999762 26.03913116 9.69E-08
2.999999762 26.03913116 9.95E-08
3.399999857 26.03913116 1.09E-07
3.799999952 26.03913116 1.05E-07
4.199999809 26.03913116 7.17E-08
4.599999905 26.03913116 2.54E-08
5   26.03913116 2.87E-09
0.166666657 27.07826042 0.001745309
0   27.07826042 0.001746275
0.333333313 27.07826042 0.00174681
0.49999997  27.07826042 0.00464339
0.833333254 27.07826042 0.003973283
1.166666627 27.07826042 2.09E-04
1.499999881 27.07826042 5.06E-06
1.874999881 27.07826042 3.72E-07
2.249999762 27.07826042 1.07E-07
2.624999762 27.07826042 8.01E-08
2.999999762 27.07826042 8.28E-08
3.399999857 27.07826042 1.10E-07
3.799999952 27.07826042 1.06E-07
4.199999809 27.07826042 7.17E-08
4.599999905 27.07826042 2.39E-08
5   27.07826042 1.31E-09
0.166666657 28.11739159 0.001725479
0   28.11739159 0.001726249
0.333333313 28.11739159 0.001727173
0.49999997  28.11739159 0.004595153
0.833333254 28.11739159 0.003936669
1.166666627 28.11739159 2.11E-04
1.499999881 28.11739159 5.33E-06
1.874999881 28.11739159 4.16E-07
2.249999762 28.11739159 1.09E-07
2.624999762 28.11739159 8.16E-08
2.999999762 28.11739159 8.40E-08
3.399999857 28.11739159 1.11E-07
3.799999952 28.11739159 1.07E-07
4.199999809 28.11739159 7.11E-08
4.599999905 28.11739159 2.27E-08
5   28.11739159 4.56E-10
0.166666657 29.15652084 0.001706611
0   29.15652084 0.001707332
0.333333313 29.15652084 0.001708043
0.49999997  29.15652084 0.004547331
0.833333254 29.15652084 0.003900517
1.166666627 29.15652084 2.13E-04
1.499999881 29.15652084 5.61E-06
1.874999881 29.15652084 4.60E-07
2.249999762 29.15652084 1.12E-07
2.624999762 29.15652084 1.01E-07
2.999999762 29.15652084 1.03E-07
3.399999857 29.15652084 1.10E-07
3.799999952 29.15652084 1.06E-07
4.199999809 29.15652084 7.03E-08
4.599999905 29.15652084 2.17E-08
5   29.15652084 9.12E-11
0.166666657 30.19565201 0.001688751
0   30.19565201 0.001689551
0.333333313 30.19565201 0.001689468
0.49999997  30.19565201 0.004499969
0.833333254 30.19565201 0.003864868
1.166666627 30.19565201 2.16E-04
1.499999881 30.19565201 5.88E-06
1.874999881 30.19565201 5.00E-07
2.249999762 30.19565201 1.15E-07
2.624999762 30.19565201 1.04E-07
2.999999762 30.19565201 1.05E-07
3.399999857 30.19565201 1.10E-07
3.799999952 30.19565201 1.06E-07
4.199999809 30.19565201 6.88E-08
4.599999905 30.19565201 2.02E-08
5   30.19565201 6.42E-31
0.166666657 31.23478317 0.001671921
0   31.23478317 0.001672991
0.333333313 31.23478317 0.001671203
0.49999997  31.23478317 0.004452467
0.833333254 31.23478317 0.003829332
1.166666627 31.23478317 2.18E-04
1.499999881 31.23478317 6.15E-06
1.874999881 31.23478317 5.33E-07
2.249999762 31.23478317 1.19E-07
2.624999762 31.23478317 1.07E-07
2.999999762 31.23478317 8.86E-08
3.399999857 31.23478317 9.31E-08
3.799999952 31.23478317 1.06E-07
4.199999809 31.23478317 6.65E-08
4.599999905 31.23478317 1.80E-08
5   31.23478317 9.74E-17
0.166666657 32.27391434 0.001655185
0   32.27391434 0.001656952
0.333333313 32.27391434 0.00165242
0.49999997  32.27391434 0.004404099
0.833333254 32.27391434 0.003793394
1.166666627 32.27391434 2.21E-04
1.499999881 32.27391434 6.43E-06
1.874999881 32.27391434 5.58E-07
2.249999762 32.27391434 1.22E-07
2.624999762 32.27391434 1.10E-07
2.999999762 32.27391434 9.08E-08
3.399999857 32.27391434 9.43E-08
3.799999952 32.27391434 1.06E-07
4.199999809 32.27391434 6.43E-08
4.599999905 32.27391434 1.56E-08
5   32.27391434 1.59E-16
0.166666657 33.31304169 0.001637113
0   33.31304169 0.001639473
0.333333313 33.31304169 0.001632962
0.49999997  33.31304169 0.004355155
0.833333254 33.31304169 0.003756959
1.166666627 33.31304169 2.24E-04
1.499999881 33.31304169 6.71E-06
1.874999881 33.31304169 5.74E-07
2.249999762 33.31304169 1.24E-07
2.624999762 33.31304169 1.14E-07
2.999999762 33.31304169 1.12E-07
3.399999857 33.31304169 1.14E-07
3.799999952 33.31304169 1.07E-07
4.199999809 33.31304169 6.21E-08
4.599999905 33.31304169 1.33E-08
5   33.31304169 6.17E-17
0.166666657 34.35217285 0.001618719
0   34.35217285 0.001621301
0.333333313 34.35217285 0.001613861
0.49999997  34.35217285 0.004306195
0.833333254 34.35217285 0.003720024
1.166666627 34.35217285 2.26E-04
1.499999881 34.35217285 6.97E-06
1.874999881 34.35217285 5.84E-07
2.249999762 34.35217285 1.26E-07
2.624999762 34.35217285 1.17E-07
2.999999762 34.35217285 1.16E-07
3.399999857 34.35217285 1.17E-07
3.799999952 34.35217285 1.08E-07
4.199999809 34.35217285 5.98E-08
4.599999905 34.35217285 1.09E-08
5   34.35217285 0
0.166666657 35.39130402 0.00160178
0   35.39130402 0.001604649
0.333333313 35.39130402 0.001595963
0.49999997  35.39130402 0.004257447
0.833333254 35.39130402 0.003682485
1.166666627 35.39130402 2.28E-04
1.499999881 35.39130402 7.19E-06
1.874999881 35.39130402 5.89E-07
2.249999762 35.39130402 1.28E-07
2.624999762 35.39130402 1.23E-07
2.999999762 35.39130402 1.22E-07
3.399999857 35.39130402 1.21E-07
3.799999952 35.39130402 1.09E-07
4.199999809 35.39130402 5.76E-08
4.599999905 35.39130402 8.67E-09
5   35.39130402 0
0.166666657 36.43043518 0.001586818
0   36.43043518 0.001590049
0.333333313 36.43043518 0.001579753
0.49999997  36.43043518 0.004209202
0.833333254 36.43043518 0.003644162
1.166666627 36.43043518 2.30E-04
1.499999881 36.43043518 7.35E-06
1.874999881 36.43043518 5.63E-07
2.249999762 36.43043518 1.32E-07
2.624999762 36.43043518 1.30E-07
2.999999762 36.43043518 1.30E-07
3.399999857 36.43043518 1.26E-07
3.799999952 36.43043518 1.11E-07
4.199999809 36.43043518 5.57E-08
4.599999905 36.43043518 6.56E-09
5   36.43043518 0
0.166666657 37.46956635 0.001574376
0   37.46956635 0.001578042
0.333333313 37.46956635 0.001565765
0.49999997  37.46956635 0.004161684
0.833333254 37.46956635 0.00360471
1.166666627 37.46956635 2.30E-04
1.499999881 37.46956635 7.47E-06
1.874999881 37.46956635 5.47E-07
2.249999762 37.46956635 1.37E-07
2.624999762 37.46956635 1.41E-07
2.999999762 37.46956635 1.40E-07
3.399999857 37.46956635 1.33E-07
3.799999952 37.46956635 1.15E-07
4.199999809 37.46956635 5.42E-08
4.599999905 37.46956635 4.71E-09
5   37.46956635 0
0.166666657 38.50869751 0.00156499
0   38.50869751 0.00156916
0.333333313 38.50869751 0.001554553
0.49999997  38.50869751 0.004114951
0.833333254 38.50869751 0.003563612
1.166666627 38.50869751 2.30E-04
1.499999881 38.50869751 7.53E-06
1.874999881 38.50869751 5.40E-07
2.249999762 38.50869751 1.43E-07
2.624999762 38.50869751 1.53E-07
2.999999762 38.50869751 1.50E-07
3.399999857 38.50869751 1.40E-07
3.799999952 38.50869751 1.19E-07
4.199999809 38.50869751 5.31E-08
4.599999905 38.50869751 3.20E-09
5   38.50869751 0
0.166666657 39.54782486 0.001559128
0   39.54782486 0.001563856
0.333333313 39.54782486 0.001546646
0.49999997  39.54782486 0.004068604
0.833333254 39.54782486 0.003520042
1.166666627 39.54782486 2.28E-04
1.499999881 39.54782486 7.46E-06
1.874999881 39.54782486 4.96E-07
2.249999762 39.54782486 1.51E-07
2.624999762 39.54782486 1.67E-07
2.999999762 39.54782486 1.62E-07
3.399999857 39.54782486 1.49E-07
3.799999952 39.54782486 1.23E-07
4.199999809 39.54782486 5.24E-08
4.599999905 39.54782486 2.01E-09
5   39.54782486 0
0.166666657 40.58695602 0.001557189
0   40.58695602 0.001562508
0.333333313 40.58695602 0.001542515
0.49999997  40.58695602 0.00402231
0.833333254 40.58695602 0.003473383
1.166666627 40.58695602 2.25E-04
1.499999881 40.58695602 7.29E-06
1.874999881 40.58695602 4.41E-07
2.249999762 40.58695602 1.61E-07
2.624999762 40.58695602 1.83E-07
2.999999762 40.58695602 1.74E-07
3.399999857 40.58695602 1.59E-07
3.799999952 40.58695602 1.28E-07
4.199999809 40.58695602 5.20E-08
4.599999905 40.58695602 1.10E-09
5   40.58695602 0
0.166666657 41.62608719 0.001559507
0   41.62608719 0.001565435
0.333333313 41.62608719 0.001542578
0.49999997  41.62608719 0.003975823
0.833333254 41.62608719 0.003422832
1.166666627 41.62608719 2.19E-04
1.499999881 41.62608719 6.98E-06
1.874999881 41.62608719 3.90E-07
2.249999762 41.62608719 1.71E-07
2.624999762 41.62608719 1.97E-07
2.999999762 41.62608719 1.84E-07
3.399999857 41.62608719 1.69E-07
3.799999952 41.62608719 1.33E-07
4.199999809 41.62608719 5.13E-08
4.599999905 41.62608719 4.35E-10
5   41.62608719 0
0.166666657 42.66521835 0.001566453
0   42.66521835 0.001572977
0.333333313 42.66521835 0.001547318
0.49999997  42.66521835 0.003928092
0.833333254 42.66521835 0.003366552
1.166666627 42.66521835 2.12E-04
1.499999881 42.66521835 6.46E-06
1.874999881 42.66521835 3.55E-07
2.249999762 42.66521835 1.84E-07
2.624999762 42.66521835 2.07E-07
2.999999762 42.66521835 1.88E-07
3.399999857 42.66521835 1.77E-07
3.799999952 42.66521835 1.35E-07
4.199999809 42.66521835 4.83E-08
4.599999905 42.66521835 7.85E-11
5   42.66521835 0
0.166666657 43.70434952 0.001578647
0   43.70434952 0.001585725
0.333333313 43.70434952 0.001557476
0.49999997  43.70434952 0.003878461
0.833333254 43.70434952 0.003302994
1.166666627 43.70434952 2.01E-04
1.499999881 43.70434952 5.50E-06
1.874999881 43.70434952 3.21E-07
2.249999762 43.70434952 2.16E-07
2.624999762 43.70434952 2.31E-07
2.999999762 43.70434952 1.96E-07
3.399999857 43.70434952 1.81E-07
3.799999952 43.70434952 1.26E-07
4.199999809 43.70434952 3.70E-08
4.599999905 43.70434952 9.44E-33
5   43.70434952 0
0.166666657 44.74347687 0.001597669
0   44.74347687 0.001605199
0.333333313 44.74347687 0.001574791
0.49999997  44.74347687 0.003826279
0.833333254 44.74347687 0.003227598
1.166666627 44.74347687 1.85E-04
1.499999881 44.74347687 3.70E-06
1.874999881 44.74347687 2.66E-07
2.249999762 44.74347687 2.53E-07
2.624999762 44.74347687 2.41E-07
2.999999762 44.74347687 1.87E-07
3.399999857 44.74347687 1.82E-07
3.799999952 44.74347687 1.01E-07
4.199999809 44.74347687 1.64E-08
4.599999905 44.74347687 0
5   44.74347687 0
0.166666657 45.78260803 0.001628722
0   45.78260803 0.001636415
0.333333313 45.78260803 0.001605077
0.49999997  45.78260803 0.003774526
0.833333254 45.78260803 0.003118682
1.166666627 45.78260803 1.40E-04
1.499999881 45.78260803 1.67E-06
1.874999881 45.78260803 2.18E-07
2.249999762 45.78260803 2.84E-07
2.624999762 45.78260803 2.88E-07
2.999999762 45.78260803 2.14E-07
3.399999857 45.78260803 1.46E-07
3.799999952 45.78260803 4.78E-08
4.199999809 45.78260803 2.25E-09
4.599999905 45.78260803 0
5   45.78260803 0
0.166666657 46.8217392  0.001690754
0   46.8217392  0.001697367
0.333333313 46.8217392  0.001670087
0.49999997  46.8217392  0.003727587
0.833333254 46.8217392  0.002997055
1.166666627 46.8217392  9.83E-05
1.499999881 46.8217392  9.59E-07
1.874999881 46.8217392  2.28E-07
2.249999762 46.8217392  2.85E-07
2.624999762 46.8217392  3.03E-07
2.999999762 46.8217392  1.91E-07
3.399999857 46.8217392  5.81E-08
3.799999952 46.8217392  6.35E-09
4.199999809 46.8217392  6.64E-18
4.599999905 46.8217392  0
5   46.8217392  0
0.166666657 47.86087036 0.00184302
0   47.86087036 0.00184606
0.333333313 47.86087036 0.001831784
0.49999997  47.86087036 0.003697354
0.833333254 47.86087036 0.002873334
1.166666627 47.86087036 8.88E-05
1.499999881 47.86087036 1.15E-06
1.874999881 47.86087036 2.26E-07
2.249999762 47.86087036 1.98E-07
2.624999762 47.86087036 1.55E-07
2.999999762 47.86087036 6.60E-08
3.399999857 47.86087036 3.55E-09
3.799999952 47.86087036 6.64E-18
4.199999809 47.86087036 6.64E-18
4.599999905 47.86087036 0
5   47.86087036 0
0.166666657 48.90000153 0.002088528
0   48.90000153 0.002102719
0.333333313 48.90000153 0.002067088
0.49999997  48.90000153 0.003463022
0.833333254 48.90000153 0.002490708
1.166666627 48.90000153 5.84E-05
1.499999881 48.90000153 8.99E-07
1.874999881 48.90000153 1.17E-07
2.249999762 48.90000153 6.36E-08
2.624999762 48.90000153 2.43E-08
2.999999762 48.90000153 3.43E-09
3.399999857 48.90000153 0
3.799999952 48.90000153 0
4.199999809 48.90000153 0
4.599999905 48.90000153 0
5   48.90000153 0
0.166666657 49.90000153 0.001112131
0   49.90000153 0.001126061
0.333333313 49.90000153 0.001093095
0.49999997  49.90000153 0.001618409
0.833333254 49.90000153 0.001088696
1.166666627 49.90000153 1.46E-05
1.499999881 49.90000153 2.99E-07
1.874999881 49.90000153 1.77E-08
2.249999762 49.90000153 0
2.624999762 49.90000153 0
2.999999762 49.90000153 0
3.399999857 49.90000153 0
3.799999952 49.90000153 0
4.199999809 49.90000153 0
4.599999905 49.90000153 0
5   49.90000153 0
0.166666657 50  0
0   50  0
0.333333313 50  0
0.49999997  50  0
0.833333254 50  0
1.166666627 50  0
1.499999881 50  0
1.874999881 50  0
2.249999762 50  0
2.624999762 50  0
2.999999762 50  0
3.399999857 50  0
3.799999952 50  0
4.199999809 50  0
4.599999905 50  0
5   50  0
```

and I hope the picture looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKtOK.jpg)